What is angular momentum and torque due to the center of mass? Give me an example
when I was studying angular momentum and fixed axis rotation in kleppner book, I had a topic on motion involving translation and rotation. On that topic, they said that components of angular momentum are two, one is the rotation of the body around its centre of mass, plus the angular momentum due to the motion of the centre of mass with respect to the origin of the inertial coordinate system. Why angular momentum due to the center of mass is considered? If so, give me an example of it.

This is a common question. Have you tried using the search function?

It's possible to justify this statement with a sort of generalization of Huygens-Steiner (or parallel axis) theorem.
It's quite easy to write the angular momentum of a body w.r.t. a point $Q$, knowing the angular momentum w.r.t. a point $P$, the momentum of the
$$\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{\Gamma}_Q & = \int_V \rho (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_Q) \times \mathbf{v} = \\
& = \int_V \rho (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_P + \mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_Q) \times \mathbf{v} = \\
& = \int_V \rho (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_P ) \times \mathbf{v} + (\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_Q) \times \mathbf{Q} = \\
& = \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_P \, + (\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_Q) \times \mathbf{Q} \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
being the momentum $\mathbf{Q} = \int_V \rho \mathbf{v}$.

An example would be the Moon orbiting the Earth. The Moon has angular momentum due to its orbital velocity around the Earth. It also has angular velocity due to its spin around its own axis. The Moon rotates around the Earth approximately once every 27 days and it spins around its own axis in about the same time, so that appears like one face is constantly facing the Earth, more or less. In the reference frame of an observer rotating with the Earth, the Moon does not appear to be spinning (and neither does the Earth), but to non rotating observer it is and since rotation is absolute, the spin about its own axis in this reference frame cannot be ignored. If we were to accelerate the spin of the Moon, it would require energy to change its angular velocity. This increase in the spin angular momentum of the Moon has to be accounted for when taking conservation of total angular momentum into account.

Imagine a point mass undergoing circular motion about the origin, like a tiny stone attached to the end of a string as it is being twirled around.
From the point of view of the stone's center of mass, it has no angular momentum because it has no size and therefore it cannot rotate. It only has translational momentum $$\vec{p} = m \vec{v}_{\rm com}$$
But from the point of view of the center of rotation, there is angular momentum that equals $$\vec{L}_{\rm origin} = \vec{r}_{\rm com} \times \vec{p}$$ as the momentum vector if some distance away from the center. This angular momentum just signifies that the body momentum acts along a line in space that does not go through the origin/center.
But for a 3D rigid body with size and orientation, the body might have rotational velocity $\vec{\omega}$ and hence has intrinsic angular momentum from the point of body center of mass that equals $$ \vec{L}_{\rm com} = {\rm I}_{\rm com}\, \vec{\omega}$$ and also it has the same translational momentum $$\vec{p} = m \vec{v}_{\rm com}$$
and to evaluate angular momentum about the origin, you need both contributions
$$\vec{L}_{\rm origin} = \underbrace{ \vec{L}_{\rm com} }_{\text{intrinsic}}+\underbrace{ \vec{r}_{\rm com} \times \vec{p} }_{\text{offset COM}}$$

All the three laws of Newton for rectilinear motion can be applied/generalized into circular motion.
Respectively,
Every (linear moving body/particle, rotational entity/system) continues its (linear, rotational) motion (in a straight line /around some fixed/variable axis in a geodesic in a dynamic system) unless compelled by an external (force, torque).
(Force, torque) is rate of change of (linear, angular) momentum
$$ F= m \ddot x= m a,  ~~ T= I \alpha = I \ddot {\theta}$$
(Force, torque) are (mass, moment of inertia) times (linear, angular) momentum.
Every (linear, angular) action has an equal and opposite (linear, angular) reaction. D'Alembert's principle.
Euler also enunciated such generalizations (not verbatim).
Examples are geodesic trajectories followed by a mass in gravity, by a satellite when shot into space with energy input (Lagrange/Hamilton). Special minute parts of celestial motion are straight lines obeyed by an apple falling from a tree to ground (Newton).
